# pymysql reading \n characters. how can I stop \n characters being run in an .sql file?

Tags: mysql, encoding, visual-studio-code, pymysql

Error:

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE 
PROCEDURE 
`sp_listProducts` (\n    SELECT p.product_id\n             , p.pr' at line 3")
```

SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_listProducts` ()
    SELECT p.product_id
         , p.product
         , u.unit
         , p.unit_quantity
         , p.unit_weight
         , p.pr_number
         , pj.project_code
         , sec.sector
         , p.supplier
         , p.packaging_info
         , loc.location                        AS project_location
         , p.comments
         , loc.location_id
         , p.product_price
         , p.price_currency
         , p.gik_number
         , p.gik_stock_id
         , p.gik_supplier_id                   AS supplier_id
         , gik.gik_supplier
         , IF(tr.in_stock > 0, tr.in_stock, 0) as in_stock
FROM tbl_product AS p
             # get all FK values for display
             LEFT JOIN tbl_unit AS u ON p.unit_id = u.unit_id
             LEFT JOIN tbl_project AS pj ON p.project_id = pj.project_id
             LEFT JOIN tbl_location AS loc ON pj.location_id = loc.location_id
             lEFT JOIN tbl_sector AS sec ON p.sector_id = sec.sector_id
             LEFT JOIN tbl_gik_supplier AS gik ON p.gik_supplier_id = gik.gik_supplier_id
             LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT product_id
             , SUM(IF(trans_type IN ('in', 'count-gain', 'wb-gain'), trans_quantity, 0))                                                as inflow
             , SUM(IF(trans_type IN ('out', 'count-loss', 'wb-loss'), trans_quantity, 0))                                               as outflow
             , SUM(IF(trans_type IN ('in', 'count-gain', 'wb-gain'), trans_quantity, 0)) - SUM(IF(trans_type IN ('out', 'count-loss', 'wb-loss'), trans_quantity, 0)) as in_stock
    FROM tbl_transaction
    WHERE deleted=0
    GROUP By product_id
) tr
                                 ON p.product_id = tr.product_id
ORDER BY p.product_id ASC;
```

I've tried changing the encoding to UTF-8 to no avail. I've also set the project settins.json "files.encoding": "utf8" in vscode; didn't work. How do I get rid of the "\n" characters being read?

Answer (score 0):

`\n` is not the villain.  Based on the error message, it is either the `CREATE` token or whatever came immediately before it.  I expect it to be a syntax error in the `DELIMITER` statement.  A common cause:

```
DELIMITER//   -- bad; need space after "DELIMITER" and the delimiter
```

Check the docs on `pymysql` -- perhaps `DELIMITER` is not used, and it is something else.

Comment: I'm not sure what fixed it, but when I closed the MySQL connection from the command line, then ran the script, all went well.